# Is it possible to make a .png (or other) image that does NOT have rectangular dimensions?

Tags: images, gimp, png, image-editing

This might be a dumb question, but is it possible to make a .png file that isn't square?

If so, how can one do this in Gimp?

Ideally I'd like one in the shape of an X.

Comment: You mean, "isn't a rectangle"? ;) Nope, not possible.

Comment: Interesting question. The vast majority of today's display devices are rectangular (a notable exception being the Motorola Aura) so I doubt non-rectangular images would be particularly useful.

Comment: I love this question, nice thought.  Why should images be rectangular?  Because someone told you that they have to be rectangular?

Comment: i wanted an image with bottle shape, searching for 2 days now, if anyone have idea please reply

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All image formats (even vector) **must maintain a rectangular border** specifying the size of the image.
*However*, one can use the transparent properties of PNG images to simulate the appearance of a non-square image.

---

Just create your image/shape, ensure the background is transparent, and save the file in the PNG format.  Make sure you *include the alpha channel* so there is a transparent background saved with the image.